# DHARMA Quantile Plots

Tags: r, residuals, zero-inflation

Can someone help me understand in very basic terms what the quantile plot to the right shows? I have read the description in the DHARMA vignette but am unable to get my head around it.

Does the cluster of points around 0 suggest zero-inflation?

[image]

Comment: (1) Did you mean at the *left* rather than the right?  (2) See [these posts about probability plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+plot+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5).  For even more, read some of [our posts about the closely related QQ plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=qq+plot+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5).

Comment: Thanks @whuber. Sorry, I must have got the name of the plot wrong. It is the plot on the right that I need help understanding.

Comment: That's a standard residual-vs-prediction plot (with some curves added).  See [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+diagnostic+plot+residual+predict*) for explanations.  I don't recall seeing any discussion here on CV about those curves of "quantile deviations," though.